# How can I send monitoring notifications to Google Chat in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apps

I want to send monitoring notifications to Google Chat in Google Cloud Platform. Under Monitoring > Alerting > Edit notificaton channels, Google Chat is not listed (only the competitor Slack, interesting...).

If I try to use a Webhook, the message never arrives in Google Chat. This is because the webhook request sent by Google has the wrong format - it does not include a "text" key in the JSON body [(see here for the format of the request sent by Google)](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#webhooks).

**Is it impossible to send monitoring notifications to Google Chat, even though the competitor Slack is available?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the current solution is to implement some script to send notification. I followed [this guide](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/webhooks) and wrote a Python Cloud Function to do the notifications.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured. It's really baffling to me that there is no proper support for this. Thanks for your help!